# Angular App hosted with IIS not handling % sign correctly

Tags: angular, url-rewriting, http-headers, iis-10

I'm encountering an issue with my Angular app that's hosted using IIS (Internet Information Services) and I want to hide server name details from response headers. The problem I'm facing is related to how the app handles the % sign in URLs. Whenever a URL with a % sign is accessed, the app doesn't seem to interpret it correctly, leading to unexpected behavior and shows the server name. When the request is made successfullly then it does not show the % sign in the URL. The server name is displayed in URL on unsuccessful requests.

[image]

For example, if i try to access http://localhost:4000 then it works fine. But if i add % sign as postfix to URL it returns **400-Bad-Request** as a response.

[image]

I have set all the angular routing setup correctly, at this state, the app is working as per the expectations. The issue is when the app is hosted on the IIS server.

I am sharing all the solutions I have tried to solve this:

hello-world is the simple angular app for displaying "hello world" hosted with IIS. I'm using IIS 10.0.19 and angular 16.1.8

[image]

I have tried URL Re-write multiple options for regex patterns and exact matches also have written handlers and module mappings.

[image]

[image]

Also i have tried custom error pages for redirection,URL-Scan.ini, and other available solutions but none of them worked for me.
I cannot get the expected results. Has anyone faced the same issue? If yes, please suggest me the correct solution apart from the above mentioned points. How can I hide the server details from URL and implement in my app.

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated. I am  open to try all the suggestion which might work to solve my issue.

Thank you in advance for all the support and help!

Comment: You should be encoding your urls when using a special character. http://localhost:4000/%25

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Percent-encoding

Comment: But it default restrict from IIS it's not even going to application when there's % sign added

Comment: `Microsoft-HTTPAPI` indicates the response coming from Windows HTTP API (http.sys), not IIS (that's why all other changes you made on IIS are useless). Like the other comment said, you will have to encode the character, or the 400 response is expected.

Comment: Issue is not 400 in response i want to hide server details from response headers

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete the "Server" response header, try the following steps:

1. Go at Site level and click “Configuration Editor”
2. Navigate to “system.webServer/security/requestFiltering” and set the value of the "removeServerVariable" to "True".

[image: strong text]

Comment: I tried this approach and different approaches for configuration but none of them is working

Comment: Have you tried all the methods in the link below? https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/remove-unwanted-http-response-headers/ba-p/369710 and https://adrianjnkns.medium.com/how-to-remove-response-headers-in-iis-2a0d555c0465 None of these work?